# Issue with AutoMapper and mapping IEnumerable collections

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Here is the code for the mapper:

```
public IEnumerable<GetQuestionsContract> Map(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<XmlNode, GetQuestionsContract>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Id, 
                options =>
                options.ResolveUsing<XmlNodeResolver<string>>().FromMember(
                    source => source.SelectSingleNode("//wfauth60xsd:questionID", namespaceManager)))
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Question, 
                options =>
                options.ResolveUsing<XmlNodeResolver<string>>().FromMember(
                    source => source.SelectSingleNode("//wfauth60xsd:question", namespaceManager)));

        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<XmlNode>, List<GetQuestionsContract>>(nodes);
    }
```

While this works, it only appears to return the first element in the IEnumerable list multiple times (as many times as their are items in the XmlNodeList).

**Update**: I've simplified the code and update the title.  The scenario works just fine if I'm mapping to one XmlNode, but the Enumeration seems to be an issue.  For example, the following code works just fine:

```
public SomeIdContract Map(XmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<XmlDocument, SomeIdContract>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Id, 
                options =>
                options.ResolveUsing<XmlNodeResolver<string>>().FromMember(
                    source => source.SelectSingleNode("//wfauth60msgs:someID", namespaceManager)));

        return Mapper.Map<XmlDocument, SomeIdContract>(document);
    }
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: something a bit similar and with another mapping technology, it could help I think: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=218448

Comment: Thanks - I've tried a similar approach, but haven't been able to get anywhere.  I'll post a response to show what I've got going...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue is not with AutoMapper, rather with XPath selecting the first node for some crazy reason.

Converting the XmlDocument to an XDocument and using Linq-to-Xml solved my issue.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out AutoMapper was using my model object's Id (Guid) property (which is normally privately set by nhiberate) as an identifier when caching the source (no matter what other properties differed).  During testing I never set the id, so the default guid was the same for all objects, which explained why only the first item in the IEnumerable was returned for all. So I had to make Id public to my tests, set the Id for each item and then everything worked.

Comment: I also saw this. It appears that automapper looks for some kind of ID field. I also didn't set this ID in my testing because it wasn't relevant, but it caused the automapper to think all the items in the collection were the same.